# cannot plot area with log axis

Tags: matlab, plot, logarithm

The code

```
x=[1e-4 1e-3 1e-2 1e-1];
y=[10 3 100 25];
figure;area(x,y)
```

returns the following output:

[image]

That is correct. But setting the scale of the y axis to logarithmic using

```
set(gca,'yscale','log');
```

makes the filling color to disappear:

[image]

I cannot understand why. There are no zeros that could mess up the log operation, so why is that?

Comment: What MATLAB version are you using? Are you doing something more than what you posted? The above code works as expected on Windows/R2015b. http://i.stack.imgur.com/j9eIJ.png

Comment: @Matt I am using R2014a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the same problem with R2013a (from what I read the problem disappeared with the new graphics engine). That's because the default `BaseValue` property of area plots is 0, so we got a problem when working in log scale.

In order to get rid of it, you can specify the `BaseValue` property of your area plot to be something different (and larger) than 0, obviously. For example a value of 1 works fine:

```
area(x,y,'BaseValue',1)
```

[image]

Comment: I now have a problem setting the path translucency with `alpha(.5)`. The translucency disappears in log scale and I cannot manage to reset it (`alpha(.5)` has no effect now)

Comment: yeah this is another bug, but this time with the 'OpenGL' Renderer. Try using the 'Painters" mode in your figure. eg. `figure('Renderer','painters')`.

Comment: oh shoot. Then I'm lost sorry!

Comment: actually now it works. I reset the renderer to 'OpenGL'. Maybe I changed it before, not sure. Thanks!

Comment: oh great then! glad to help